# Jquery in a View page stops working after ASP.NET MVC Core is puplished to IIS

Tags: javascript, jquery, iis, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc

In my ASP.NET MVC Core project, the JQuery in the following view works fine on VS2015 (that uses IIS Express). But when the same app is published to IIS on the **same** developer machine (Windows 10) , it's not working. The JQuery code in the view below removes the $ and comma symbols from the input in `<td>@Html.EditorFor(r => r[i].SaleAmount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "saleAmt" } })</td>` control in the view before the form is submitted to the controller that saves the data to a SQL Server Db. But this functionality is not working  after app is published to IIS. As a result, user input in that control is not saved to the database. I can see the exact same view is there in the published folder (that I'm using as a physical path to application directory in IIS). Accept this issue, the entire app in IIS is working fine. the `IIS version` on windows 10 is 10.0.14393.0:

**UPDATE**:

1. I had mistakenly copied the wrong Jquery code. I've corrected that Jquery in the `View` below. But the issue remains the same: The Jquery works in VS2015 (with IIS Express) but not after the app is published to the IIS on the same machine.
2. I used [this article](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Jun/06/Publishing-and-Running-ASPNET-Core-Applications-with-IIS) to publish my ASP MVC Core app to the IIS. The app works fine except the only Jquery (shown below) that I'm using, it seems, is not called. Both the IIS Express and local IIS are on the same machine.
3. Following is the Javascript/Jquery related folder structure under wwroot folder of the project. And I see that the same structure along with its files is published to the IIS physical path directory of the project.

[image]

**Model**:

```
public class SaleViewModel
{
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C0}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public float? SaleAmount { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

**Controller**:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateSales(List<SaleViewModel> model, string returnUrl = null)
{
    ....
}
```

**View**:

```
@model IList<MyProj.Models.SaleViewModel>
....
<form id="target" asp-controller="DbRelated" asp-action="UpdateSales" asp-route-returnurl="@ViewData[" ReturnUrl"]" method="post" onsubmit="myJsFunction()">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            ....
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.EditorFor(r => r[i].SaleAmount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "saleAmt" } })</td>
                    ....
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
</form>

@section scripts
{
    <script>
        $("#target").submit(function () {
        var textboxes = $('.saleAmt');
        $.each(textboxes, function(index, item) {
        var text = $(this).val().replace(/[$,]/g, '');
        $(this).val(text);
       });
      });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Do you have an errors in your browser console?

Comment: Also, what is the point of the `parseFloat` function here? Yo are not saving the result of it.

Comment: @DavidG There was an error in the Jquery code. I have copied the correct Jquery above. But the issue remains the same. 1. There is no error shown in the console. 2. I've added an UPDATE section to my post above. See if that can help.